# Scope with callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, scope, push

I have part of an if statement below that does a few api calls to facebook and instagram. I am having trouble getting the 'instagram' part of this to push the data to an array... I am thinkig is a scope issue but not sure - Maybe you can tell me why I am getting nothing pushed into my array. The comments explain what happens. I cant get the instagram posts to push to the instaFormattedPosts array.

```
else if(responseData.fbData && responseData.fbData.instaId){
            //First Get Fb Posts - I push them into this array, 'fbFormattedPosts' then use thatlater to update state. This one works, fbPost object gets pushed forEach() fbPosts.data response. 
            let fbFormattedPosts = []
            response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${fbDataTemp.pageId}/feed?access_token=${fbDataTemp.pageAccessTokenLong}`)
            let fbPosts = await response.json()
            fbPosts.data.forEach(post => {
                if(post.message){
                    let fbPostObject = {
                        type: 'text',
                        data: post.message,
                        link: `http://www.facebook.com/${post.id}`,
                        date: post.created_time,
                        postId: post.id,
                        rockOn: []
                    }
                    fbFormattedPosts.push(fbPostObject)
                }
            })

            //Get IG Media Ids - This returns a list of instagram id's. 
            let instaFormattedPosts = []
            response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/${fbDataTemp.instaId}/media?access_token=${fbDataTemp.pageAccessTokenLong}`)
            let instaPosts = await response.json()

            //Get IG Posts - Alright here is where I cant get the instaPostObject to push to isntaFormattedPosts array...
            instaPosts.data.forEach(async instaId => {
                const instaResponse = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${instaId.id}?fields=id,media_url,timestamp,username&access_token=${fbDataTemp.pageAccessTokenLong}`)
                let instaPostRendered = await instaResponse.json()

                let instaPostObject = {
                    type: 'instagram',
                    data: instaPostRendered.media_url,
                    link: `http://www.instagram.com/${instaPostRendered.username}`,
                    date: instaPostRendered.timestamp,
                    postId: instaPostRendered.id,
                    rockOn: [],
                }
                instaFormattedPosts.push(instaPostObject)
                console.log(instaPostObject) //Returns the object with the right details.
            })

            console.log(instaFormattedPosts) // returns empty array.. 


            //Set All Posts 
            setPosts([ 
                ...responseData.posts, 
                ...fbFormattedPosts
                   .filter(({postId}) => 
                      !responseData.posts
                         .find(post => post.postId == postId)),
               ...instaFormattedPosts
             ])
        }
```

Comment: you have an async foreach and you are not waiting for it to end. when you run this you will probably get the console.log(instaFormattedPosts) before you execute the first element on the loop.

Comment: I seeee! wow! Ok I'll try to figure out how to get it to wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async await` don't work with `forEach`, it will just invoke

```
// this will just loop through all the data inside and instaPosts
// and not wait to complete inside block

instaPosts.data.forEach(async instaId => {
    // your code
    instaFormattedPosts.push(instaPostObject)
    console.log(instaPostObject) //Returns the object with the right details.
})
```

**Solution : is simple for loop**

```
for (let i=0 ; i< instaPosts.data.length ; i++) {
    const instaId = instaPosts.data[i];
    const instaResponse = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${instaId.id}?fields=id,media_url,timestamp,username&access_token=${fbDataTemp.pageAccessTokenLong}`)
    let instaPostRendered = await instaResponse.json()

    let instaPostObject = {
        type: 'instagram',
        data: instaPostRendered.media_url,
        link: `http://www.instagram.com/${instaPostRendered.username}`,
        date: instaPostRendered.timestamp,
        postId: instaPostRendered.id,
        rockOn: [],
    }
    instaFormattedPosts.push(instaPostObject)
    console.log(instaPostObject) //Returns the object with the right details.
}
console.log(instaFormattedPosts) // <---- CHECK NOW
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Thanks for the lesson - I didnt relize the forEach wouldnt wait to get done before going to the console.log of my array.

Comment: @NickMcLean, Glad to know it helped